# How to set up a matrix with a fixed pattern

Tags: matlab, matrix

I need to write a script to automatically setup a matrix `A`. The size of this matrix is linked to the value of another variable in the workspace, `N`. In general, A will have `N + N*(N-1)/2` rows and `N` columns.

The first `N` rows and `N` columns are basically just a diagonal matrix, which is easy to setup using `diag`.

I'm having problems setting up the lower part of the matrix. Basically, it needs to have the following form:

```
-1  0  0  0
 0 -1  0  0
 0  0 -1  0
 0  0  0 -1
 1 -1  0  0
 1  0 -1  0
 1  0  0 -1
 0  1 -1  0
 0  1  0 -1
 0  0  1 -1
```

I'm sure the pattern is clear.

How do I code this so that Matlab sets up this matrix for ANY value of `N`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Performance version including preallocation.

```
N=4;
result = zeros(N*(N+1)/2,N+1);
t = N;
endpos = 0;
for t = N:-1:1 
    result(endpos+1:endpos+t,:) = [zeros(t, N-t) ones(t,1) -eye(t)];
    endpos = endpos + t;
end
result = result(:,2:end);
```

Note that I have replaced the `while` loop as you seem to prefer a `for`.

---

I will leave the original here as well for comparison:

Here you go:

```
result = [];
N = 4;
t = MaxN;
while t > 0
    block = [zeros(t, N-t) ones(t,1) -eye(t)];
    result = [result; block];
    t = t-1;
end
result = result(:,2:end);
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way of doing it by avoiding a `while` loop?

Comment: @Fayyaadh Its not too hard to change this into a `For` loop, but what do you hope to achieve? (And why)

Comment: I just want everything to be as readable and efficient as possible. I personally prefer `for` loops over `while`, I hardly use `while` loops in any of my code so I'd just like to use the type of code that I'm used to writing myself. Also, MATLAB is complaining that the `result` matrix isn't pre-allocated.

Comment: Then you can use `for N = MaxN:-1:1`, however that is mostly a matter of taste. If you want more efficiency you should actually **preallocate** `result` and keep track of where you want to place the result inside the loop. (I will leave this as an excercise) --- Im not sure whether it is possible to avoid loops alltogether, but I doubt that it will make your code more readable.

Comment: OK seems as though the code isn't doing quite what I want. Using your example with `N = 4`, the lower part of the matrix `A` (i.e. below the `4x4` diagonal square matrix I've described in my OP) should be `6x4` (i.e. `N*(N-1)/2xN`) but it's actually `10x5`.

Comment: Apologies! My OP had an error! See the edit for what `A` needs to look like. Notice that my example for A is for `N=4`. I'm having issues setting up rows 5 to 10. (rows 1 to 4, columns 1 to 4 is just a diagonal matrix)

Answer (score 3):

With some algebraic manipulation:

```
L=(N*(N+1)/2):-1:1;
R=ceil((sqrt(8*L+1)-1)/2);
A=bsxfun(@eq, N-1:-1:0, R')-bsxfun(@eq, N:-1:1, (L-(R.*(R-1))/2).');
```

Comment: Though I personally find it harder to read, it is definately a bit faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thank everyone! I will post my own solution here (doesn't pre-allocate though). Might adjust it to @Dennis's solution.

```
N = max(size(a));
P = N*(N-1)/2;

A = zeros(N+P,N);

A(1:N,1:N) = diag(-a);

B=[];

for i = N-1:-1:1
    Block = [zeros(i,N-1-i) ones(i,1) -eye(i)];
    B = [B; Block];
    clear Block
end

A(N+1:end,:) = B;
clear N P B i
```

Comment: Note that for `N = 1000`, my solution now takes about 8 seconds, but without preallocation this becomes over 800 seconds!